# Sources for Minhag of partial Pesach Cleaning if away

Tags: passover, minhag, cleaning, chametz-leaven

I am looking for any sources for the Minhag of only needing to clean one room in your house for Pesach if you are going to be away for the whole chag.

Comment: IIRC _Mishna B'rura_ 436 notes that the reason we don't say a _b'racha_ on early _b'dika_ is that such _b'dika_ is only in fulfillment of the rule that we must do a _b'dika_ and not in preparation for _biur_. I don't have a source handy (which is why I'm not writing this as an answer), but the custom to clean one room is likewise in fulfillment of the rule that we must do a _b'dika_ and not in preparation for _biur_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.kashrut.com/Passover/pdf/Pesach_Gram_Q_and_A_2011.pdf

> Chazal obligated each person to search
>   for Chometz on the night before
>   Pesach. [If one leaves town before
>   that time, he is still obligated to
>   search for Chometz the night before he
>   leaves, although no blessing is
>   recited for that search.] In the
>   opinion of many Poskim, the search for
>   Chometz is obligatory whether or not
>   one owns his chometz by the time
>   Pesach arrives, since once the
>   Rabbinic ordinance was enacted, it
>   cannot be abrogated regardless of the
>   circumstances. Consequently, selling
>   the house to a non-Jew does not free
>   one from his personal obligation to
>   search for Chometz.
>
> A solution to this problem is to set
>   aside one room in the house, even a
>   small one, and not sell it to the
>   non-Jew along with the rest of the
>   house. That room should be cleaned for
>   Pesach and thoroughly searched for
>   Chometz on the night before Pesach,
>   with the proper blessing recited for
>   the Bedikah. One who will have already
>   gone out of town by the night before
>   Pesach should follow the same
>   procedure on the night before he
>   leaves – but he may not recite a
>   blessing on the Bedikah.